Multiple Date Difference Calculation
I'm trying to create a table in SQL that shows the difference in hours between each deposit for each user e.g (1st deposit Vs 2nd deposit, 2nd deposit Vs 3rd deposit, 3rd deposit Vs 4th deposit etc...)
here is the original table:
with q1 as (SELECT 
[UserId],
[DepositAttemptDate], 
[AmountSystem]
FROM [dbo].[v_DepositAttempts_Marketing]
WHERE [DepositAttemptDate] >= '2024-01-01' AND [Status] IN ('Completed', 'Complete', 'Confirmed') AND [DepositType]=''
ORDER BY [UserId] ASC, [DepositAttemptDate] DESC)




User
Deposit Date
Value




83815-fa85-466b-aaa7-00029c5
2024-10-30 12:42:58.793
8.698677800974


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-02-28 20:38:59.883
253.390000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-02-28 19:09:26.323
253.390000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-02-28 18:15:13.223
253.390000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-02-28 17:54:17.340
253.390000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-02-06 19:43:12.757
115.140000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-01-30 13:36:56.937
253.390000000000


62ac8-5d7f-464a-993c-00039b1
2024-01-09 14:20:03.440
405.040000000000


17f62-01c7-4a9c-ba28-0003b7f
2024-05-15 18:50:18.350
51.500000000000


17f62-01c7-4a9c-ba28-0003b7f
2024-03-21 22:59:57.217
51.500000000000


17f62-01c7-4a9c-ba28-0003b7f
2024-01-21 13:24:44.393
51.500000000000


17f62-01c7-4a9c-ba28-0003b7f
2024-01-03 20:13:14.167
51.500000000000


76763-384a-46cb-9a08-0004393
2024-09-06 18:51:29.677
103.000000000000


76763-384a-46cb-9a08-0004393
2024-09-05 00:01:44.587
51.500000000000


76763-384a-46cb-9a08-0004393
2024-08-25 03:42:08.290
103.000000000000




Do not tag spam, pick one database program and use that as the tag, drop the rest.

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear? The use of brackets ([]) to delimit identify, and the schema dbo implies SQL Server, but you need to correct your post here.

You also don't ask anything here; you tell us what you need to dol, but not what isn't working about your attempt, or what the difficulty you're having solving the problem is.

Your query isn't complete. You have to select from q1, not just declare it.

Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve].

Assuming this is SQL Server and guessing how accurate you want the results to be (as you didn't specify either), then you could try one of these
DATEDIFF(HOUR, LAG(DepositAttemptDate, 1, DepositAttemptDate) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY DepositAttemptDate), DepositAttemptDate) AS FullHours

or
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(DepositAttemptDate, 1, DepositAttemptDate) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY DepositAttemptDate), DepositAttemptDate)/60.0 AS DecimalHours

The first will give you full hours, the second will give you a decimal representation, so for example, three hours and 6 minutes would return 3.1
In both examples, we've used LAG to get the previous datetime. If no previous record is found (first record for each UsersId) we've return the current record's DepositAttemptDate so the DATEDIFF will return 0 in these cases.
